# Blank returned by ClosingPeriod function in SSAS calculations script

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

Following is the expression :
ClosingPeriod([Period].[Fiscal Dates].[Date], [Period].[Fiscal Dates].CurrentMember)

Can anyone suggest why it might return blank ?

Updated Full Script :

```
CASE  
    ClosingPeriod(
        [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE],
        [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
        ) 
WHEN null THEN 
    MAX
        (NONEMPTY 
            (
            [Period].[Fiscal Dates].[Date].Members 
            * 
            [Measures].[Indiv Count]
            ),     
        [Period].[Date].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY
    )
ELSE 
    ClosingPeriod(
        [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE],
        [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
        )
```

I am using this script to assign a value to variable.In this expression always the null case is being executed.

Comment: please add the rest of the script - context is very important in MDX?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, but more an approach to find it.

In complex calculations, it helps to add some helper measures just to understand what happens. I normally make these measures from sub expressions of a large calculation, adding `.Name` to members, or applying `SetToStr` on sets (assuming they are of reasonable size to be displayed). Thus, measure definitions like

```
[Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER.Name
```

and

```
ClosingPeriod(
    [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE],
    [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
    ).Name
```

can make it more transparent what happens if you add these measures to your query.

Furthermore, it normally helps to try calculations online in the `WITH` clause of a `SELECT` statement before putting them into the calculation script, as it is faster to change this and see the immediate result of the change.

Comment: +1 will try this against my Adventure Works version of his calc

Comment: ...I can get `WHEN null` to be True in my second script against `AdWks`. The OP seems to say his clac is _always_ `null`. Any ideas Frank?

Comment: @whytheq Actually, this is a borderline case and I am not sure what the `CASE ClosingPeriods(...) WHEN` really compares. In numeric context, `NULL` and `0` should be equal. And if you want to check if a member reference is empty, you should not use `<reference> = null` but `IsEmpty(<reference>)`. Hence, the variant of the `CASE` expression that checks a complete condition in every `WHEN` would be more appropriate here, as you can state more clearly what you really compare.

Comment: Ok Frank let me alter the second script in my post to reflect your advise - I will comment on findings.

Comment: Frank - I've added a third script to my post. I think this calculation has a contradition in it - if [Date].[Fiscal] is empty/null then why include [Date].[Fiscal] in the max calculation?!

Answer (score 0):

Need to see all your script to be able to analyse as context of that expression counts for a lot in `MDX`.

Try this on the Adventure Works cube:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Close] AS
        CLOSINGPERIOD( 
            [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE]
            , [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
        ).Properties('key0', TYPED)
SELECT 
    {
    [Measures].[Close] 
    } on 0,
    {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].MEMBERS}
ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The following return seems ok: `CLOSINGPERIOD` is returning the last member of the `Date` level of the `Fiscal` hierarchy:

[image]

---

Including a `CASE` structure I still get a return:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Close] AS

        CASE  
            ClosingPeriod(
                [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE],
                [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
                ).MEMBER_KEY 
        WHEN null THEN 
            MAX
                (NONEMPTY 
                    (
                    [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE].Members 
                    * 
                    [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
                    ),     
                [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_KEY
            )
        ELSE 
            ClosingPeriod(
                [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE],
                [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER
                ).MEMBER_KEY 
        END
SELECT 
    {
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],
    [Measures].[Close] 
    } on 0,
    {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].MEMBERS}
ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

To try to force null for the Fiscal hierarchy in the following I'm using Calendar on rows:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Close] AS 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
        IsEmpty
        (
          ClosingPeriod
          (
            [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE]
           ,[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember
          ).Member_Key
        ) 
      THEN 
        Max
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE].MEMBERS * [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
          )
         ,[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember.Member_Key
        )
      ELSE 
        ClosingPeriod
        (
          [Date].[Fiscal].[DATE]
         ,[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember
        ).Member_Key
    END 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Close]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS} ON 1 //][Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].MEMBERS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This returns the following:

[image]

Comment: Actually I am creating a SSAS project using Visual Studio.I am writing this script in calculations script editor and I want to save the value returned by CLosingPeriod in a variable.

Comment: @Kash ok. In what context is it "showing blank" - for example if the hierarchy `[Period].[Fiscal Dates]` is not used in a query, on either rows or columns, then your calc will be blank as there is effectively no currentmember.

Comment: I have updated the question with full script.Please have a look.

Comment: @whytheq Did you intentionally mix the `[Date].[Calendar]` and `[Date].[Fiscal]` hierarchies in your third attempt?

Comment: @FrankPl - that is deliberate so that Fiscal is not on either rows or columns - that is so that we get null for Fiscal to test the THEN section of the CASE. How else would we encounter a null?